# Create reactive form in angular using the nested json object

Tags: angular

I know question like this have been already asked but it did not worked out for me.
Actually I have large nested json value like this:

```
 "Q-1": {
            "question": {
                "text": "What are your hopes and goals for this year? (This could be about family, friends, community, faith, work, education, health, or more.)",
                "bounding-box": []
            },
            "answer": {
                "original": {
                    "handwritten-text": {
                        "value": "",
                        "bounding-box": []
                    }
                }
            },
            "page": {
                "page_no": "",
                "page_dim": [],
                "accuracy_score": ""
            }
        },
        "Q-2": {
            "question": {
                "text": "What things in your life bring you the most happiness?",
                "bounding-box": []
            },
            "answer": {
                "original": {
                    "handwritten-text": {
                        "value": "",
                        "bounding-box": []
                    }
                }
            },
            "page": {
                "page_no": "",
                "page_dim": [],
                "accuracy_score": ""
            }
        },
..................
```

now I want to create a reactive from on basis of this JSON value like this:

```
this.userForm= this.fb.group({
 Q1: new FormGroup({
   answer: new FormGroup({
     original: new FormGroup({
       "handwritten-text": new FormGroup({
         value: new FormControl(''),
         "bounding-box": new FormControl('')
       }) 
     })
   })
 }),
 Q2: new FormGroup({
  answer: new FormGroup({
    original: new FormGroup({
      "handwritten-text": new FormGroup({
        value: new FormControl(''),
        "bounding-box": new FormControl('')
      }) 
    })
  })
}),
})
})
```

so I think I have to first traverse the large nested json value and then create different method that will create the FormGroup with the appropriate key and value and then push the formGroup to the original formArray, But I have facing issue while implementing it.

So is there any other easy way to do it.

Comment: It would be great if you also provide the code that you have tried so far ;) otherwise question will be closed...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your solution looks complicated, I did something similar recently and I solved with interfaces, for example this part:

```
"question": {
                "text": "What are your hopes and goals for this year? (This could be about family, friends, community, faith, work, education, health, or more.)",
                "bounding-box": []
            },
            "answer": {
                "original": {
                    "handwritten-text": {
                        "value": "",
                        "bounding-box": []
                    }
                }
            }
```

Look that the user has to type just the "bounding-box","value" and "text"... you can get the data with a simple form (no nested) and in your component.ts reorganize everything as your interface says....

Here is an example that I solved:

INTERFACE

```
export interface PieInterface{
    dataSet:PieDataSet,
    labels: string[],
    title: string
}

export interface PieDataSet{
    backgroundColor: string[],
    data: number[]
}
```

COMPONENT

```
myForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    //single values
    title: [],
    pointsQuantity: [, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]],

    //arrays
    labels: this.fb.array([["", Validators.required],], Validators.required),
    data: this.fb.array([["", Validators.required],], [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]),
    backgroundColor: this.fb.array([["#24C5E0", Validators.required],], Validators.required),
    
  })


setValues(){
      if(this.myForm.valid){
  
        const dataSet: PieDataSet = {
          backgroundColor: this.myForm.controls.backgroundColor.value,
          data: this.myForm.controls.data.value
        }
  
        const myChart: PieInterface = 
        {
          title: this.myForm.controls.title.value,
          labels: this.myForm.controls.labels.value,
          dataSet: dataSet
        }
  
        this.pieService.data$.emit(myChart)
  
      }}
```